# SimuLTE: Simulating D2D and non-D2D UEs simultaneously

Tags: omnet++, simulte

Using SimuLTE, is it possible to simulate D2D and non-D2D UEs simultaneously in the same cell? If yes, can anyone briefly explain the steps?

All the examples provided with the package deal with either only D2D or only non-D2D UE simulation.

Thank you.